# How do I drive a switch carrying a low voltage with a high voltage signal?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, bjt

I have a microcontroller with 3.3 V IO pins. I have an external noisy input that is either 0 V (off) or between 12-36 V (on). Due to uncertainty concerning the on voltage amount, I do not wish to use a voltage divider.

Can I use a NPN BJT in saturation mode, with 3.3 V at the collector, my external signal at the base, and the IO input pin at the emitter, or will the large voltage difference between the base and everything else do something strange?

If this approach doesn't work, how should I read this signal?

Comment: Is this to be read via a digital IO port or is it an analogue value?

Comment: Look at "high side driver/switch", 3.3V tolerant. These come with a built-in regulator and lots of them are designed for 24V nominal. I guess most of them still work with 5V though.

Comment: @Andyaka it's a binary value. To be more specific, an external device triggers a latch releasing what is supposed to be a 24V signal with up to one amp, but in reality the voltage is all over the place.

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to use a resistor divider but this sounds like a job for an 11:1 divider (10k over 1k?), a cheap 1.024V reference, and a comparator with hysteresis.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these approaches will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8y0us.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left the signal is inverted. When the input is high, the output is low, and vice versa, but you should be able to deal with this inversion in software.

On the right I use a zener diode to prevent OUT2 from rising above 3.3V. This arrangement will not invert.

Your original suggestion uses the transistor in common-collector mode (emitter follower), which would also work, but in this application such high input potentials could cause the +3.3V supply to sink current too, which I would not recommend. It's not a "bad" idea though, since it would not invert:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG3eWZ.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Just use a divider sized for the minimum input. Use a diode clamp (Schottky e.g. BAT54S) to prevent activating the MCU's ESD clamp diode.

Or if you don't need it read quickly, use an ADC input, size the divider for the maximum sensed voltage, and implement whatever kind of filtering, threshold and hysteresis you like in software.

External analog filtering is required in any case, and most likely ESD protection too.

An NPN can't be hard wired to the input, but when used after a resistor divider, you have the effect that, as base approaches and exceeds VCC, emitter approaches VCC, and both B-C and B-E junctions become forward-biased, clamping the voltage just so. The downside is, the B-E voltage adds a tempco (you wouldn't use this for limiting a precision/analog input), and negative inputs aren't clamped. Note you need a pull-down resistor from emitter to GND. Whereas the diode-clamped case, can clamp within say 0.5 V of each rail, and with a series resistor between diode and MCU pin, ESD current can be limited.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a NPN BJT in saturation mode, with 3.3 V at the collector, my external signal at the base, and the IO input pin at the emitter, or will the large voltage difference between the base and everything else do something strange?

Yes, this can be made to work safely.

You will need a current-limiting resistor in series with the base. When the input voltage exceeds approx. 3.9 V, the transistor will saturate and the base will be clamped at approx. 0.6 V above the collector.

You also will need a resistor between the emitter and GND to assure a logic zero state when the input is low and the transistor is off.

So much for safety and reliability.  Now, about that noise...

Your circuit suggestion increases the system noise immunity in the high state, but not the low state.  If the input signal can be ambiguous in the 0-3 V range, this could appear at the emitter as a 2.4 V signal, which will be seen by a GPIO pin as a logic 1.

If you want to increase the low-state noise immunity, such that it takes a minimum input signal of, for example, 6 V-ish to be seen as a logic 1, then put a 6.2 V Zener diode in series with the base (in addition to the current-limiting resistor). Now the transition level is approx. centered between the minimum high-state voltage (12 V) and the maximum low-state voltage (approx. 2.3 V before adding the Zener).